# is there command or script for compare multiple files and print the output based on first two columns

Tags: merge

I have multiple files (vcf), so based on the first two columns, need to append the value of the remaining samples to the first file/ create new files. so how can I do this? Even I need to add dots where the value is no there. Please let me know Perl script/any command is enough to do this job.

file1

1 152 GT:DP 1/1:5

1 162 GT:DP 0/1:4

file2

1 152 GT:DP 0/1:5

1 155 GT:DP 0/1:6

file3

1 155 GT:DP 1/1:5

1 162 GT:DP 0/1:4

desired output

1 152 GT:DP 1/1:5  0/1:5    ./.:.

1 155 GT:DP ./.:.     0/1:6   1/1:5

1 162 GT:DP 0/1:4  ./.:.      0/1:4

I tried the below command
`paste {file1,file2} | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$8}' > out.txt`
I got the result :

1 152 GT:DP 1/1:5 0/1:5

1 162 GT:DP 0/1:4 0/1:6

Here, the first row is correct, but in the second row we have values like 155 and 162 in file1 and file2, it won't consider these, and just merge both files and took value(but I want to add dots where the values, not matches)